# finding count of repeate of a number in a vector

Tags: r

I have a vector like this:

```
 v <- c(1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 6, 6, 1, 3)
```

I want to find the unique values and the number of repeate of each value.

this command:

```
unique(v)
```

gives me only:

```
[1] 1 5 2 6 3
```

but I would like to have something like this:

```
[value] [repeate]
 1          3
 5          3
 2          2
 6          2
 3          1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a job for `table`:

```
table(v)
# v
# 1 2 3 5 6 
# 3 2 1 3 2
```

Also, remember that there is a `data.frame` method for `table` that will convert it to a long form like you show in your question:

```
data.frame(table(v))
#   v Freq
# 1 1    3
# 2 2    2
# 3 3    1
# 4 5    3
# 5 6    2
```